# How to create zip of a specific folder using shutil

Tags: python, zip

I'm trying to zip all the folders of a particular directory separately with their respective folder names as the zip file name just the way how winzip does.My code below:

```
folder_list = os.walk('.').next()[1] # bingo
print folder_list

for each_folder in folder_list:
    shutil.make_archive(each_folder, 'zip', os.getcwd())
```

But what it is doing is creating a zip of one folder and dumping all other files and folders of that directory into the zip file.LIke that it is doing for all the folders inside the current directory.
Any help on this !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a little more research in **shutil**, I'm now able to make my code work. Below is my code:

```
import os, shutil

#Get the list of all folders present within the particular directory
folder_list = os.walk('.').next()[1]

#Start zipping the folders
for each_folder in folder_list:
    shutil.make_archive(each_folder, 'zip', os.getcwd() + "\\" + each_folder)
```

Comment: Mayby use os.path.join() to join path, it's safer.

Answer (score 0):

I don;t think that is possible. You could look at the source.

In particular, at line 683 you can see that it explicitly passes compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED if your Python has the zipfile module, while the fallback code at line 635 doesn't pass any arguments besides -r and -q to the zip command-line tool.

You could try this one:

```
args = ['tar', '-zcf', dest_file_name, '-C', me_directory, '.']
res = subprocess.call(args)
```

If you want to get list of directories use some well written libs:

```
for (root, directories, _) in os.walk(my_dir):
  for dir_name in directories:
     path_to_dir = os.path.join(root, dir_name)// don't make concat, like a+'//'+b, thats not enviroment saint
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I got my code working.Please check my answer.

Comment: Ok, sorry I wasn't too much help, I posted some tip in my answer update:) Hope it will be of some use.